# Push notification not displayed using web-push and service workers

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, mern, web-push

I have converted my MERN application to a PWA using the service worker files that are pre-generated with `create-react-app`. It seems to be working ok as I can see the service worker is activated in the dev tools.

Now I would like to be able to send push notifications.

I have installed `web-push` and in my `App.js` file I am requesting permission from the user to receive notifications with this code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
  registration.pushManager
    .subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_PUSH_PUBLIC,
    })
    // additional code to store user's subscription to db
});
```

The notification I am trying to send comes from a `Like` button on a user's post. After handling the like, my function runs this request, sending the `_id` of the user who created the post and a payload, to my server:

```
await axios.post(
  `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/send-push-notification`,
    {
      _id: res.data.postedBy,
      payload: {
        title: 'Post Liked',
        body: 'Someone liked your post',
        icon: base64 string of my logo,
      },
    },
);
```

My backend receives this request, finds the correct user, stringifies the payload, and sends the notification with `web-push`.

```
webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:myemailaddress',
  process.env.WEB_PUSH_PUBLIC,
  process.env.WEB_PUSH_PRIVATE
);

router.post('/send-push-notification', async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findById(_id);

  const subscription = user.subscription;
  const payload = JSON.stringify(req.body.payload);

  webpush
    .sendNotification(subscription, payload)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).send('Push notification sent');
  })
})
```

I am then receiving a status response of 200 on the client, suggesting everything is working up until this point.

The issue I am having is that the notification is not being displayed on the user's device.
In my `service-worker.js` file I have added this block, which I believe is responsible for this part:

```
self.addEventListener('push', (e) => {
  const data = e.data.json();
  console.log('Push received...', data);
  self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: data.body,
    icon: data.icon,
  });
});
```

This code is not being triggered though as the console.log is not displayed either.

To test the file I added another simple event listener to fire on 'install':

```
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  console.log('Service Worker installed');
});
```

And this log is never shown either. Which leads me to believe the issue lies with this file not being read.

Here is the block within `serviceWorkerRegistration.js` that is registering the service worker:

```
export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit https://cra.link/PWA'
          );
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Any help or ideas on how to resolve this issue would be hugely appreciated. TIA